# select query with where clause and column name should be present at right side

Tags: sql, oracle

Usually the query should be like below.

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE first_name = 'alex'
```

Can we write like this?

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE 'alex' = first_name
```

Additionally, if it works, why?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you expect it work either way round?

Comment: Yes.  The order of the operands does not matter.

Comment: Yes it *works*, but is not necessary as SQL **doesn't use `==`**.

Comment: Both `'alex'` and `first_name` are just expressions.  One happens to be a scalar constant, the other is a scalar from a column.  But they're still both simple expressions, and they're still both scalars.  I'm unsure why you think it would matter which way round your compare them with an equality operator.  Equality of scalars is always commutative...

Answer (score 1):

This is an Oracle's [condition](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions002.htm#SQLRF52107) with 3 expressions, one is [column expression](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions005.htm#SQLRF20043) and the other  simple expression

[image]

Both are valid [expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions001.htm#SQLRF52066) `expr`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be work. Because it success for `expression` [condition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions001.htm)

Comment: link is sql server while question is about oracle

Comment: don't sighted. but logic the same I think

Answer (score 0):

This works, and it does so because `=` goes both way, meaning: what is to the left of the equals is equals to what is to the right of the equals, and the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

This works on MS-SQL-Server and I am use this will work on Oracle too - why? Why not? For the server it does not matter if he compares columnes, variables oder static values or strings. It has always avaluate both side of the '='.